# Compress snapshot backups with duplicates

Tags: backup, compression

I have a set of backups of mostly photos. The directory looks sort of like this:

```
backup/Day1/photos/1.jpg
               .../2.jpg
backup/Day2/photos/2.jpg
               .../3.jpg
               .../4.jpg
backup/DayN/photos/2.jpg
               .../3.jpg
               .../9.jpg
```

Files with same name are identical. There are many duplicates. Due to the way the backup system works, it's not possible to create incremental backup directly. I always get the entire dump each day.

If I want to create a compressed archive for a date range, say Day 5~9, **what is the best tool/compression algorithm to do that， which does deduplication well?** (I'm not counting on compressing the jpeg itself)

Comment: There's no best compression algorithm when you're attempting to compress files that *are already compressed*.

Comment: Which OS? Also, what are you looking to do - skip dupes inside the archive so only a single copy of each file exists, but extraction restores the multiple copies? As for "best" algo, that might keep changing but there are definitely [some algos/tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PAQ) that use specialised models for JPEG compression and consequently can handle them better than others.

Comment: I'm looking for algorithm that does deduplication well, not jpeg compression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ZPAQ](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/zpaq.html) is a little known archiver which does deduplication, and, AFAIK, the only one. Because ZPAQ also does versioning, you can keep every single backup in a single archive, reducing space usage even more.

Or, you could use a version control system, such as Git, which does file deduplication automagically.

Or, if you want to something more complicated, you could tinker with Btrfs or ZFS, which are filesystems with deduplication built-in. Btrfs' deduplication is not as good as ZFS' though.

Answer (score 1):

WIM (Windows Imaging Format) is probably what you are looking for. While ZPAQ is nothing short of an amazing tool (I use it myself), it does block based de-duplication whereas WIM's de-duplication is file based (MS calls it SIS - Single Instance Storage, see [Microsoft Deployment Toolkit
Using MDT and Single-Instance Storage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee914607.aspx)).

Since the question mentions that it is the files themselves that are repeated it can be argued that file based de-duplication would be a better fit - especially taking into account that we are talking about JPEGS.

Both WIM and ZPAQ:

- Do Incremental updates
- Have error detection support
- Support strong encryption
- Are supported on at least both Windows and Linux (see [wimlib -
  the open source Windows Imaging (WIM) library](https://wimlib.net/) - for WIM)
- Have strong compression support
- Are stable

WIM Advantages:

- Widely adopted and supported
- Faster
- Similar results to ZPAQ

WIM Disadvantages

- File level de-duplication (useless for files (especially if large) with small changes).

ZPAQ Advantages:

- Block Level de-duplication - amazing for massively repeated data with small changes between file versions, for instance, but not only
- Amazing tool, unique in what it does and how it does it as far as I know of

ZPAQ Disadvantages:

- a bit slower (not as much as I would imagine), when de-duplication is on and compression is set to max (5), so only marginal advantage if file level de-duplication is enough
- Not widely adopted
- No good GUI support (it matters for restores and archive navigation)